# (pyqt5) How to print the result of a function without pressing any buttons?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am learning pyqt5 now. I want to print the result of a loop function to the QTextBrowser. For example, to print "hello world" every second. But I don't want to press any pushbutton. I want to let "hello world" automatic print when I run this script. I have tried the following code:

```
class Ui_Dialog(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    _signal=QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_Dialog,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self._signal.connect(self.print_out)

             .....................
             .....................

    def emit_(self):
        self._signal.emit("Hello world!")

    def print_out(self, string):
        print (string)
        self.textBrowser.append(string)

def call(): 
    while True:   
        emit_()
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWin = Ui_Dialog()
    myWin.show()
    call()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, it doesn't work. In the terminal, I can see the print result, but this result can not print in the textBrowser. The textBrowser is always empty.

Answer (score 1):

> The QTimer class provides repetitive and single-shot timers.
>
> The QTimer class provides a high-level programming interface for timers. To use it, create a QTimer, connect its timeout() signal to the appropriate slots, and call start(). From then on, it will emit the timeout() signal at constant intervals.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(QtWidgets.QWidget):
#    _signal=QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_Dialog,self).__init__()
#        self.setupUi(self)
#        self._signal.connect(self.print_out)

        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, interval=1000, timeout=self.print_out)
        timer.start()

#    def emit_(self):
#        self._signal.emit("Hello world!")

    def print_out(self, string="Hello world!"):
        print (string)
        self.textBrowser.append(string)

#def call(): 
#    while True:   
#        emit_()
#        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWin = Ui_Dialog()
    myWin.show()
#    call()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]